# Lazarus doesn't run with GDB

Tags: gdb, lazarus

I install Lazarus and GDB. When i check like that `gdb -help` i receive

```
This is the GNU debugger.  Usage:

    gdb [options] [executable-file [core-file or process-id]]
    gdb [options] --args executable-file [inferior-arguments ...]

Selection of debuggee and its files:

  --args             Arguments after executable-file are passed to inferior
  --core=COREFILE    Analyze the core dump COREFILE.
  --exec=EXECFILE    Use EXECFILE as the executable.
  --pid=PID          Attach to running process PID.
  --directory=DIR    Search for source files in DIR.
and so on
```

In `Tools->Options->Debugger->General-> GNU debugger(gdb) to /usr/bin/gdb` But I can't run my project, I always received

```
The GDB command:
"-file-exec-and-symbols "
did not return any result.

The GDB process is no longer running.
```

In google there a lot of ideas but no one can help me.

Comment: Is anything set for the `Debugger_Startup_Options` setting?

Comment: No, what exactly it have to be there?

Comment: Having nothing there is usually OK, but try setting it to `--interpreter=mi`

Comment: Thanks, but nothing happen

Comment: OK, take it out and we'll try another tack. What operating system and numeric version (Ubuntu 14.04, Centos 7, Windows 10) are you running?

Comment: I use OS X 10.9.2 and i took gdb [there](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/)